# Flex prevent datagrid from editing after a drag & drop

Tags: apache-flex, drag-and-drop, advanceddatagrid

I have an AdvancedDataGrid with editable parameter to "true". My problem is that after a successfull drag & drop, the item is being edited and I don't want this to happen.

I tried to create a custom advancedDataGrid with this:

```
override protected function dragCompleteHandler(event:DragEvent):void{
            trace("call dragCompleteHandler");
            super.dragCompleteHandler(event);
            clearAllSelection();
            selectedItem = null;
        }
```

But It doesn't work and I just don't know if I have to stop an event with preventDefault or something else. I also looked into the Adobe AdvancedDataGrid  code and it seems that after a dragcomplete event there is nothing dispatched...

How can I stop this annoying edition (or focus) after a drag & drop?

**EDIT 27/02/2012**

The solution is to listen to DRAG_START and DRAG_COMPLETE events, in the constructor (or init function of the component):

```
addEventListener(DragEvent.DRAG_START,itemDragStartHandler);
addEventListener(DragEvent.DRAG_COMPLETE,itemDragCompleteHandler);
```

and :

```
protected function itemDragStartHandler(event:DragEvent):void
    {
        editable = "false";
    }

    protected function itemDragCompleteHandler(event:DragEvent):void
    {
        editable = "true";
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try listening to the `itemEditBeginning` event. It is cancelable, so you can use `preventDefault()` to stop the editor from showing. You'll probably need to store the items that have been dragged / are being dragged in order to prevent the edit event only when a drag & drop has occurred. I'm not sure in which order the `itemEditBeginning` and the drag & drop events are dispatched, so'll need to experiment a little bit. Using `trace` is a good way to debug those events...

Another solution I can think of is to set `editable` to `false` when the drag & drop starts and set it to `true` when the drag & drop is complete.